# existing subnest are replaced with new subnets in DataLake gen2

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I would like to add virtaul network and subnets for a DataLake Gen2 using this template

```
  {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "Region": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "DE",
            "allowedValues": [ "DE", "ES", "FR", "DK", "PL", "NL", "BE", "PT" ]
    },
    "Location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "West Europe"
    },
    "SubscriptionName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Subscription-DEV"
    },
    "Environment": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "DEV"
    },
    "VnetCidr": {
        "defaultValue": "127.27.0.0/16",
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": { "description": "Cidr range for the vnet." }
    },
    "PrivateSubnetCidr": {
        "defaultValue": "127.27.0.0/18",
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": { "description": "Cidr range for the PrivateSubnet." }
    },
    "PublicSubnetCidr": {
        "defaultValue": "127.27.64.0/18",
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": { "description": "Cidr range for the PublicSubnet." }
    },
    "SpokeSubnetCidr": {
        "defaultValue": "127.27.128.0/18",
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": { "description": "Cidr range for the PublicSubnet." }
    }
},
"variables": {
    "ResourceGroupName": "[concat('analytical-',parameters('Region'))]",
    "VirtualNetwork": "[concat('analytical-vnet-',toLower(parameters('Region')),'-',if(equals(parameters('Location'),'westeurope'),'we','ne'))]",
    "Subnet": "[concat('analytical','-subnet-',toLower(parameters('Region')))]",
    "DataLakeGen2": "[concat('analytical0',tolower(parameters('Environment')),'0dls20',if(equals(parameters('Location'),'westeurope'),'we','ne'))]",
    "NSGDatabricks": "[concat('analytical-nsg-',toLower(parameters('Region')),'-','databricks-',if(equals(parameters('Location'),'westeurope'),'we','ne'))]",

    "PrivateEndPointStorageAccount": "[concat('analytical0pep0',tolower(parameters('Region')),if(equals(parameters('Location'),'westeurope'),'0we','0ne'))]",
    "DNSZoneName": "[concat('privatelink.blob.core.windows.net' )]",

    "DatabricksPrivateSubnet": "[concat(variables('Subnet'),'-dbrprivate')]",
    "DatabricksPublicSubnet": "[concat(variables('Subnet'),'-dbrpublic')]",
    "DatabricksSpokeSubnet": "[concat(variables('Subnet'),'-dbrspoke')]",
    "Databricks": "[concat('analytical-dbr-',toLower(parameters('Region')),'-',if(equals(parameters('Location'),'westeurope'),'we','ne'))]",
    "vnetId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',variables('ResourceGroupName'),'/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/',variables('VirtualNetwork'))]",
    "nsgId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId,'/resourceGroups/',variables('ResourceGroupName'),'/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/',variables('NSGDatabricks'))]",
    "privateLinkServiceId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/beep-',toLower(parameters('Environment')),'/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/',variables('DataLakeGen2'))]",
    "privateDnsZoneId": "[concat('/subscriptions/',subscription().subscriptionId, '/resourceGroups/',variables('ResourceGroupName'),'/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones/',variables('DNSZoneName'))]",
    "managedResourceGroupName": "[concat('databricks-rg-', variables('DataBricks'), '-', uniqueString(variables('DataBricks')))]"


   },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "name": "[variables('ResourceGroupName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]"
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2019-05-01",
            "name": "[variables('ResourceGroupName')]",
            "resourceGroup": "[concat('analytical-',parameters('Region'))]",
            "dependsOn": [ "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/',variables('ResourceGroupName'))]" ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
                            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
                            "name": "[variables('NSGDatabricks')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "securityRules": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Microsoft.Databricks-workspaces_UseOnly_databricks-worker-to-worker-inbound",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "Required for worker nodes communication within a cluster.",
                                            "protocol": "*",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "*",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 100,
                                            "direction": "Inbound",
                                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Microsoft.Databricks-workspaces_UseOnly_databricks-control-plane-to-worker-proxy",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "Required for Databricks control plane communication with worker nodes.",
                                            "protocol": "tcp",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "5557",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "AzureDatabricks",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 102,
                                            "direction": "Inbound",
                                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Microsoft.Databricks-workspaces_UseOnly_databricks-control-plane-to-worker-ssh",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "Required for Databricks control plane management of worker nodes.",
                                            "protocol": "tcp",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "22",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "AzureDatabricks",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 101,
                                            "direction": "Inbound",
                                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Microsoft.Databricks-workspaces_UseOnly_databricks-worker-to-databricks-webapp",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "Required for workers communication with Databricks Webapp.",
                                            "protocol": "tcp",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "443",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "AzureDatabricks",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 100,
                                            "direction": "Outbound",
                                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Microsoft.Databricks-workspaces_UseOnly_databricks-worker-to-sql",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "Required for workers communication with Azure SQL services.",
                                            "protocol": "tcp",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "3306",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "Sql",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 101,
                                            "direction": "Outbound",
                                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Microsoft.Databricks-workspaces_UseOnly_databricks-worker-to-storage",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "Required for workers communication with Azure Storage services.",
                                            "protocol": "tcp",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "443",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "Storage",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 102,
                                            "direction": "Outbound",
                                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Microsoft.Databricks-workspaces_UseOnly_databricks-worker-to-eventhub",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "Required for worker communication with Azure Eventhub services.",
                                            "protocol": "tcp",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "9093",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "EventHub",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 104,
                                            "direction": "Outbound",
                                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Microsoft.Databricks-workspaces_UseOnly_databricks-worker-to-worker-outbound",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "description": "Required for worker nodes communication within a cluster.",
                                            "protocol": "*",
                                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                                            "destinationPortRange": "*",
                                            "sourceAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
                                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "VirtualNetwork",
                                            "access": "Allow",
                                            "priority": 103,
                                            "direction": "Outbound",
                                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [],
                                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }


                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
                            "apiVersion": "2020-04-01",
                            "name": "[variables('VirtualNetwork')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "addressSpace": {
                                    "addressPrefixes": [ "[parameters('VnetCidr')]" ]
                                }
                            },
                            "dependsOn": [ "[variables('NSGDatabricks')]" ],
                            "resources": [
                                {
                                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
                                    "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
                                    "name": "[concat(variables('VirtualNetwork'), '/',variables('DatabricksPrivateSubnet'))]",
                                    "dependsOn": [ "[variables('VirtualNetwork')]" ],
                                    "properties": {
                                        "addressPrefix": "[parameters('PrivateSubnetCidr')]",
                                        "networkSecurityGroup": { "id": "[variables('nsgId')]" },
                                        "serviceEndpoints": [
                                            {
                                                "service": "Microsoft.Storage"

                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "delegations": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "databricks-del-private",
                                                "properties": { "serviceName": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces" }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
                                    "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
                                    "name": "[concat(variables('VirtualNetwork'), '/',variables('DatabricksPublicSubnet'))]",
                                    "dependsOn": [ "[variables('VirtualNetwork')]", "[variables('DatabricksPrivateSubnet')]" ],
                                    "properties": {
                                        "addressPrefix": "[parameters('PublicSubnetCidr')]",
                                        "networkSecurityGroup": { "id": "[variables('nsgId')]" },
                                        "serviceEndpoints": [
                                            {
                                                "service": "Microsoft.Storage"

                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "delegations": [
                                            {
                                                "name": "databricks-del-public",
                                                "properties": { "serviceName": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces" }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
                                    "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
                                    "name": "[concat(variables('VirtualNetwork'), '/',variables('DatabricksSpokeSubnet'))]",
                                    "dependsOn": [ "[variables('VirtualNetwork')]", "[variables('DatabricksPrivateSubnet')]", "[variables('DatabricksPublicSubnet')]" ],
                                    "properties": {
                                        "addressPrefix": "[parameters('SpokeSubnetCidr')]",
                                        "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Disabled",
                                        "delegations": []
                                    }
                                }

                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces",
                            "apiVersion": "2018-04-01",
                            "name": "[variables('Databricks')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "managedResourceGroupId": "[concat(subscription().id, '/resourceGroups/', variables('managedResourceGroupName'))]",
                                "parameters": {
                                    "customVirtualNetworkId": { "value": "[variables('vnetId')]" },
                                    "customPublicSubnetName": { "value": "[variables('DatabricksPublicSubnet')]" },
                                    "customPrivateSubnetName": { "value": "[variables('DatabricksPrivateSubnet')]" }
                                }
                            },
                            "dependsOn": [ "[variables('VirtualNetwork')]", "[variables('DatabricksPrivateSubnet')]", "[variables('DatabricksPublicSubnet')]", "[variables('DatabricksSpokeSubnet')]" ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones",
                            "apiVersion": "2018-09-01",
                            "name": "[variables('DNSZoneName')]",
                            "location": "global"
                        }

                    ],
                    "outputs": {}
                }
            }

        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2019-05-01",
            "name": "[concat('beep-',parameters('Environment'),'-',parameters('Region'))]",
            "resourceGroup": "[concat('beep-',parameters('Environment'))]",
            "dependsOn": [ "[variables('ResourceGroupName')]" ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "name": "[variables('DataLakeGen2')]",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
                            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
                            "apiVersion": "2019-06-01",
                            "sku": {
                                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                                "tier": "Standard"
                            },
                            "kind": "StorageV2",
                            "properties": {
                                "networkAcls": {
                                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                                    "defaultAction": "Deny",
                                    "virtualNetworkRules": [
                                        {
                                            "id": "[concat(variables('vnetId'),'/subnets/',variables('DatabricksPublicSubnet'))]",
                                            "action": "Allow"
                                            //"state": "succeeded"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "id": "[concat(variables('vnetId'),'/subnets/',variables('DatabricksPrivateSubnet'))]",
                                            "action": "Allow"
                                            //"state": "succeeded"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                 

                                },
                                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": true,
                                "encryption": {
                                    "services": {
                                        "file": { "enabled": true },
                                        "blob": { "enabled": true }
                                    },
                                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                                },
                                "accessTier": "Hot"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
                            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
                            "name": "[variables('PrivateEndPointStorageAccount')]",
                            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "privateLinkServiceConnections": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "[variables('PrivateEndPointStorageAccount')]",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "privateLinkServiceId": "[variables('privateLinkServiceId')]",
                                            "groupIds": [ "blob" ],
                                            "privateLinkServiceConnectionState": {
                                                "status": "Approved",
                                                "description": "Auto-Approved",
                                                "actionsRequired": "None"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "manualPrivateLinkServiceConnections": [],
                                "subnet": { "id": "[concat(variables('vnetId'),'/subnets/',variables('DatabricksSpokeSubnet'))]" },
                                "customDnsConfigs": []
                            }
                        },
                        {

                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/privateDnsZoneGroups",
                            "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
                            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
                            "name": "[concat(variables('PrivateEndPointStorageAccount'), '/default')]",
                            "dependsOn": [ "[variables('PrivateEndPointStorageAccount')]" ],
                            "properties": {
                                "privateDnsZoneConfigs": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "[concat('privatelink-blob-core-windows-net')]",
                                        "properties": { "privateDnsZoneId": "[variables('privateDnsZoneId')]" }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "guidOutput": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[variables('privateDnsZoneId')]"

        }
    }
}
```

I deploy my template via this powershell script:

```
$templatefile="Analytics\azuredeploy.json"
$parameterFile="Analytics\azuredeploy.parameter.json"
New-AzSubscriptionDeployment -TemplateFile $templatefile -TemplateParameterFile $parameterFile -Location westeurope
```

as you can see everything is parametrized. If I run my template for the second time old subnets are replaced with new subnets. Do you know what cause the problem?

Comment: Could you provide your complete template including `template.json` and `parameters.json`? And how did you deploy the template?

Comment: I have edited my post

Comment: do the new subnets have new names?  (or how do you know they are being replaced?)

Comment: Yes they have new names, but the IP Adresses are same